# XCFramework is not being generated within the KMM library [SOLVED]

Tags: android, kotlin-multiplatform, xcframework

[SOLVED]

I Have created a Kotlin Multiplatform Library project and haven't added any custom code per se.
Now I am trying to build the XCFramework out of the KMM project. But I am getting empty directories instead of `.xcframework` files.

[image: XCFramework directories]

I have tried the basic things like,
1. Clean and re-build the project.
2. Invalidating the cache and restarting the Android Studio.

But those didn't worked, Looking for an answer or any references would also serve the purpose.

Comment: You should post more config and details. It'll be very hard to figure out what's happening here. However, you said "haven't added any custom code per se". If there's no code it's probably not building anything. Try adding some code. Just a class. Not "real" code.

Comment: To keep it simple, I created a plain KMM library project from Android studio and tried building it, after successful build process, studio generated this empty directories.

Comment: Does the plain project have Kotlin files in it? If not, the Kotlin compiler probably doesn't build anything.

Comment: Yes, It has the `Greeting.kt` file. You can try it out just by creating a new android studio project -> new KMM Library , and try building it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by running the following command to build the XCframework

```
gradlew assembleXCFramework
```

[image]